# Repeated sprintf format pattern - string literals versus const char string and compiler optimization

Tags: c, printf, c-strings

In C, is it common that the compilers will optimize repeated string literals? I was working with sprintf statements that repeated the same string literal for the format with a const char array and noticed that the memory usage did not change in the map file. The compiler used in this test is IAR for embedded systems.

To elaborate, there are six sprintf statements used for creating a ping string to different addresses similar to:

```c
sprintf(pingString, "ping %s 3 1\r", "127.0.0.1");
sprintf(pingString, "ping %s 3 1\r", primaryDNS);
```

I replaced the format strings with a const char:

```c
const char pingCommandFormat[] = "ping %s 3 1\r";
sprintf(pingString, pingCommandFormat, "127.0.0.1");
sprintf(pingString, pingCommandFormat, primaryDNS);
```

Then compiled and checked the mapping file and noted that there were no changes in memory used.

Keeping the string literals instead of using the const char string is ideal for readability, but optimizing memory usage is prudent in embedded systems. Optimizations should never be expected from compiler behavior but is this type of behavior common in different compilers?

Comment: It is not atypical that multiple identical string literals point to the same memory location.

Comment: Which memory usage did you check? Are you sure that you didn't introduce extra RAM usage for your array? Instead of an array you could also use a pointer.

Comment: As you already mentioned: Don't expect anything. But common (sub)string usage is not too exotic. It might even happen that `"hello world"` and `"world"` share same memory

Comment: You could investigate this by doing `char *p1 = "ping %s 3 1\r", *p2 = "ping %s 3 1\r"; printf("%p %p\n", p1, p2);`.

Comment: @Gerhardh I should have mentioned that both ro and rw memory were consistent between compilations

Comment: Did you also check stack usage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Constant folding is common, even without optimizations enabled.

For example, with the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    const char *str1="hello";
    const char *str2="hello";
    printf("%p\n", (void *)str1);
    printf("%p\n", (void *)str2);
    printf("%p\n", (void *)"hello");
    printf("%p\n", (void *)"hello");
    return 0;
}
```

Built on CentOS 7.2 with gcc 4.8.5 as `gcc -g  -Wall -Wextra -o x1 x1.c`, it outputs:

```
0x400630
0x400630
0x400630
0x400630
```

As you can see, in each of the 4 places `"hello"` appears in the code it refers to the same string literal.

Answer (score 1):

I am not a ware of a compiler not doing this optimisation – but if I remember correctly, it is not mandated by the standard.

If it is for readability:

```
void createPingString(char const* address)
{
    sprintf(pingString, "ping %s 3 1\r", address);
}
```

Maybe even better:

```
void sendPing(char const* address);
```

containing all the rest of the procedure as well...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, sendPing() is a really elegant way to consolidate the code.